# "Unable to lock database - Failed to synchronize databases"

Tags: manjaro, pacman, software-updates, database

I was trying to update the recommended stuff in my manjaro machine but this error occurred.
I have no idea how to solve it.

I was getting the error

```
Invalid or corrupted databases
```

so I updated the mirrors as recommended [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/invalid-or-corrupted-database/92815)

But then this new error came up.
Can anyone help me out? I also don't know what informations might be good to share with you to make the task of solving this problem easier so please tell me what is necessary and I update de question.

---

Additional information:

When I try deleting `/var/lib/pacman/db.lck`:

```
/var/lib/pacman/db.lck: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check for existence of `/var/lib/pacman/db.lck` and delete it. It is possible that the previous failed update failed without unlocking the process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, that file is already deleted:/

Comment: It seems you are using pamac instead of pacman. Try `pamac update --force-refresh` as suggested in [https://forum.manjaro.org/t/114762](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pamac-update-unable-to-lock-database-failed-to-synchronize-databases/114762). If that doesn't help, describe what you are doing and post the full output you get.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Maybe post a answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages `Failed to synchronize databases` and `Invalid or corrupted databases` indicate you are using pamac instead of pacman (because the pacman source code does not contain these strings). Try running

```
pamac update --force-refresh
```

as this seems to fix it according to this [Manjaro forum thread](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pamac-update-unable-to-lock-database-failed-to-synchronize-databases/114762).

I recommend learning how to use pacman's command-line interface since Manjaro's software has a reputation of being buggy.